# Update records depending on fields - Django

Tags: python, django

I want to override the `save` method of a model in Django.

Consider this model:

```
class OtherClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class MyClass(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(OtherClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    myfield1 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    myfield2 = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    myfield3 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    myfield4 = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    myfield5 = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

What I want, is to update the model only if `myfield5` is present in whatever form or view the user is filling. This is the current `save` method I have:

```
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        fieldgroup = f"{self.myfield2}\n{self.myfield3}"
        self.myfield5 = f"{fieldgroup}\n{self.field1} {self.field4} {self.field5}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any ideas?

Maybe it would be better to achieve this on a form rather than directly into the model?

Comment: you've told what you want but haven't told us the issue. What's not working?

Comment: Hi, sorry, right now it just saves regardless of the fields present, some of them or not blank or null True, however, what I want is to update the model only when myfield5 is filled, which as you can see is comprised of a concatenation of some others, i dont know if this explains the situation?

Comment: wouldn't `if self.myfield5` do that?

Comment: Yep, but, what confuses me, is the super().save method, in the sense that what should i declare in the case it isnt present? I mean, i save the record,  but if myfield5 is present on a lets say, form editing, of this model, i will update it on db, otherwise i wont, if record is created, save, if its updated, save only if myfield5 is present, does that make any sense?

Comment: I don't understand. If it's empty, just leave it empty and it'll be saved as empty. Or you don't want to save anything at all in that case? That would be strange as this means any changes to the other fields would just be lost.

Comment: Yes, I mean, if it's created for the first time, you just save, even if myfield5 isn't present, as You say it will be saved as empty, but, if record is updated, (there comes my confusion) then save only if myfield5 is present, it's a bit weird, some changes will probably be lost, but that's the requirement :/, do you have any example in that case?

Comment: If you want to check during the `save()` method whether or not the model is being created, you can do `if self.pk`, which will be `False` if this is the first save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `self.pk` to determine whether the object was already previously saved or not (the first time `self.pk` is `None`).

So in combination with `self.field5`, you can do this:

```
if self.pk and self.field5:
    self.field5 = ...  # update field5 as you need
    super().save(...)
elif not self.pk:
    super().save(...)
# no saving if self.pk and not self.fields
```

Comment: Thank You very much, gotta go this way, if anything else arises I will ask a new question, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use required=True in your Model field or Form field